# how can i calculate time difference between nstimer fire and nstimer invalidate

Tags: ios, time, nstimer, nstimeinterval

```
- (IBAction)clickedAction:(id)sender {
[_timer fire];}

-(void)updateValue:(NSString*)value ofItem:(int)itemId{
     ......
    BOOL success = [database executeUpdate:updateSwitch];

    if (success == YES) {
          ....
     }
    [_timer invalidate];}
```

In first function I start nstimer when a button is clicked.

I want to do the `updateValue()` function return `false` if the database function does not return `true(success==yes)` in 5 seconds.

If success is not return yes in 5 seconds, the timer must finish and `updateValue()` function return `false`.